# Regex get string inside two strings

Tags: regex, replace

I have searched all but couldn't find anything.
I have:

```
[BBSHORTCODE_button align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT[/BBSHORTCODE_button]
```

I want to remove first part and last part of string and get

```
button align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT
```

I have tried:

```
string.replace(/\[BBSHORTCODE_([^\/]*)\]/g, function(d, c) {...})
```

and it removed the first part as I want and the last character: `]`. So is it possible to replace my code so that it removed last part: `[/BBSHORTCODE_button]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the string

```
var s = "[BBSHORTCODE_button align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT[/BBSHORTCODE_button]";
```

you can apply replace twice on each border of the string and you get what you are looking for:

```
s = s.replace(/\[BBSHORTCODE_/g, '').replace('\[/BBSHORTCODE_button\]', '');
```

the output string is:

```
"button align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT"
```

the second solution is to use match instead of replace, so for the same string s apply match this way:

```
s.match(/\[BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\[\/BBSHORTCODE_button\]/)[1];
```

Notice that match returns an array where your desired result is in the second position that's why there is [1] after the instruction.

more generally, if you have an other string like:

```
l = "[BBSHORTCODE_something align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT[/BBSHORTCODE_something]";
```

using match in the following way:

```
l.match(/\[BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\[\/BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\]/)[1];
```

will return the desired result which is, as far as I understand:

```
 something align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT
```

here is a full working test scenario:

```
 var  l = "[BBSHORTCODE_something align=none css=none000 color=#FFFFFF]CONTENT[/BBSHORTCODE_something]";
 console.log(l.match(/\[BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\[\/BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\]/)[1]);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed Ali Jamaoui but it doesn't  comfortable. Could you please write solutions for this example :

 `return string.replace(/[BBSHORTCODE_([^/]*)]/g, function(d, c) {return c;})`
And if its not too difficult, one mor correction:` BBSHORTCODE_` could be `BBSHORTCODE_button`, `BBSHORTCODE_link etc`., so please write for general solution.
Thanks

Comment: and (/\[BBSHORTCODE_(.*)\[\/BBSHORTCODE_button\]/)[1] doesent works

Comment: check the latest edit at the end it addresses the general pattern [BBSHORTCODE_something... it is working fine here, if it doesn't work for you please put your error message. Ideally put a jsfiddle demo